# Line plot doesn't show when used with a datetime variable on the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I'm trying to plot a bar graph that is accompanied by two line graphs. The barplot shows fine but I can't seem to get the lines plotted above the barplot. Here's the code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,9))
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
g=sns.barplot(date_new, df["Net xG (xG - Opponent's xG)"].astype("float"), palette="coolwarm_r", hue=df["Net xG (xG - Opponent's xG)"].replace({"-":0}).astype("float"), dodge=False, data=df)
plt.plot(date_new, -df["Opponent's xG"].astype("float"), color="gold", marker="o")
plt.plot(date_new, df["xG (Expected goals)"].astype("float"), color="indianred", marker="o")
g.set_xticklabels(stuff[::-1], rotation=90)
g.get_legend().remove()
g.set(xlim=([-0.8, 46]))
plt.show()
```

[image: Output of the above code, no line plots]

`date_new` variable used for the x-axis is in datetime64[ns] format. A weird thing I noticed is that if I reformat `date_new` as a string like `date_new.astype("str")`, the line plots show but the order is reversed.

I tried to "re-reverse" the order of which dates are sorted by by changing the x-axis variable to `date_new[::-1]`, but that doesn't seem to change the line plots' order.
[image: By changing date_new to a string format the line plots get visible, however this time I can't reverse the order of x values which are reversed.]

Here's a screenshot of how the x (Date) and y (xG) axis variables look on the dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

Comment: The ticks labels are _cosmetic_. Changing the labels will not re-order the plot. `str` ordering and datetime ordering would be different. Some sample data to reproduce the plot as well as some expected output would make answering this question easier.

Comment: Your x axis is pretty clearly _not_ in dates.  I don't know how seaborn works, but I expect that setting `data=df` leads to the x axis being categorical with the categories being the strings you see along the xaxis.

Comment: @HenryEcker I can't share the data since it could cause some copyright issues, however if I were to describe the axis variables:

-**y:** I'm trying to plot the change in expected goals (xG) for and against a football club for each match played throughout the season. The red line is supposed to stand for the xG produced by the mentioned club for a specific game, and the yellow one is meant to be xG produced by opposition against that club in that game. xG and xG against are floats between 0-5.

-**x:** I'm trying to plot the change in xGs in a chronological order, against datetime vars.

Comment: @JodyKlymak The data I'm using is goal expectations a football club has produced per game. I'm using datetime data on x-axis, I replaced the axis labels with strings, which are names of football clubs that the club I'm analyzing has played against in those dates. My goal is to switch the beginning and ending points of both line plots.

Comment: @HenryEcker I added a screenshot of the columns I'm working with. The problem is that the first point on both line plots correspond to the last bar on the graph. So the line plots are inverted. Labels and bars are correct. The line plots do not show at all unless I change the datetime column as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to combine a bar graph with two line plots. It seems you are having issues matching your x-axis variables. As @Henry Ecker said above, the x axis labels on a bar plot are cosmetic and do not represent an actual date time axis. Consequently, the x-axis values for your bar plot are simply the numbers 0 to 46.

To fix your problem, simply make the line plot x values a list from 0 to 46.

I simulated your data and demonstrate the solution in the example below.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create data 
# there are 46 rows each representing a game against some other club
# colums include: date of game, opposing club, club goals, opposing club goals
# goal range is 0-5

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date':pd.date_range(start='1/2021', end='7/1/2021', periods=46),
    'club':['Team: ' + str(n) for n in range(1,47)],
    'goals': np.random.randint(0, 5, 46),
    'opposing_goals':np.random.randint(0, 5, 46)
})

df['net_goals'] = df.goals - df.opposing_goals

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,9)) 
sns.set_style("darkgrid")              

g=sns.barplot(
    x=df.date, y=df.net_goals, 
    palette="coolwarm_r", hue=df.net_goals, dodge=False, data=df
    )

plt.plot(np.arange(0,46), -df.opposing_goals, color="gold", marker="o") 
plt.plot(np.arange(0,46), df.goals, color="indianred", marker="o")

g.set_xticklabels(df.club, rotation=45)
g.get_legend().remove()
g.set(xlim=([-0.8, 46]))
```

Comment: First of all, apologies for the limited amount of information I could make available in my initial question. I'm still somewhat new to Stack Overflow and Python. Using `np.arange()` did solve my problem. I'm as grateful as one can be, and thanks for going through all that trouble to help a stranger out. Appreciate it big time.